# Pass email body user enter value to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, outlook, html-email, email-attachments

I am sending mail asp.net mvc controller to outlook. The email body has text area and attachment input box. User should enter the comments in text area and attachemnt. then when click button the value should be passed to asp.net mvc controller. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook (as well as any other email clients) doesn't support placing any scripts in the message body or execute any code, so input controls are not supported in the message body. That is made for security reasons.